# Regex to test at least one number,can be alphanumeric,and should allow some special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I  am writing a regex for zipcode for following requirements.

1. It must contain at-least 1 number;
2. It could be alphanumeric;
3. Only special character allowed would be `-`, `space` and/or `#`.

Though it seems very simple,but I couldn't write it successfully. I am newbie to regex and not having smooth time with regex.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: If you're writing it, how far did you get?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried?

Comment: You were close. You're missing a `-` in your character set, and you haven't covered "It must contain at-least 1 number". The answer below deals with that in the lookahead `(?=.*\d)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
/^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d #-]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Try With The Follwoing Example :**

***HTML Part :***

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var zipcode_expression = /^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d # ,-]+$/;
if (zipcode_expression.test($.trim($('#zipcode').val())) == false){
    alert('invalid zipcode');
}
});
</script>
<input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" value="jo h,n1#-">
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.